# I'm experiencing a JSON Decode Error while using the Youtube API for Subscribers (Python)

Tags: json, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I'm using Python 3.8 in my program using the YouTube API to scrape a list of my subscribers from my YouTube channel. I have the correct code, created the right credentials (API Key and OAuth2), and I downloaded my Json File for client ID. I'm experiencing this tracecall when I run the program:

[image]

If it's helpful to see the code, let me know, but I can't seem to fix this JSON error. With that said, I'm completely inexperienced to this so it could just be something simple that I don't know about.

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines: avoid posting images. Error messages produced by programs should appear here as plain text (by a simple copy-paste operation; even Windows' command terminal allows that).

Comment: Your `Json File` (as you refer it) is not an actual valid JSON text. Check that out!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was having trouble getting that code text to appear in the normal readable format. I'll work on that. In regards to the JSON, I fixed it by downloading the correct JSON file. I'm now on to the next issue lol.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question. I had to download the JSON file from a different location. Initially, I downloaded the JSON by entering the OAuth 2 Credential section specifically and clicking Download JSON file.
It turns out that you you don't have to do that. Once you sign into your Google Consoles for the API and are on this screen:
[image]

You can click on the download button on the OAuth 2 row. That should work as the JSON file you need.